# #unix-path tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We didn't have a [#unix-path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix-path) tag until I just made one. (I hope I haven't made trouble by doing so.) The [#PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/path/info) tag (all-caps) is specifically about the environment variable, but not what we refer to on a day-to-day basis, such as the *path* to a file.

Still, there are many questions about the *paths*:

- [Canonical paths: why are they needed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77451/)
- [Why does sshd requires an absolute path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109380/) (improperly tagged with [#PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/path/info))
- [Find the size of file from absolute path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530396/)

See just one massive list of possible posts that could benefit from such a tag:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=absolute+relative+paths
- Searching for existing answers with such a tag sure would be helpful.

Should we have one?

If so:

- This would be a meta question related to it.
- What would the definition and scope be?
- It should probably include canonical, relative, and absolute, right?
- It should probably exclude `$PATH` from the already-existing [#PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/path/info) tag, right?
- What should it be called?

  - [#unix-path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix-path)
  - `#posix-path`
  - `#paths`
  - Something else?

If we don't need one:

- Why not, even with so many posts about the specific concept?
- Seriously asking, how would it be problematic for our site to unify related questions?

Answer (score 4):

The [filenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filenames) tag's excerpt says:

> File name is a name used to identify a file uniquely on given file system.

To uniquely identity something in a filesystem, the full path is required, so I think this *tag* encompasses paths. At any rate, I don't see a need for separate tags for names vs paths (the only distinction between the two in a Unix system is, after all, that while both can't contain the `\0` character, names in addition can't contain `/`), so if a new tag is made, they should be synonyms.

Questions would be better served by adding tags related to the context in which the path or filename becomes a problem.